# Mostrar busqueda desde textbox a listview desde un stored procedure MySQl

Tags: c#

Estoy comenzando con bases de datos (MySQL) con C# y estoy utlizando `ListView` y un `DataGrid` para mostrar la tabla. 
Tengo un problema cuando hago la búsqueda completando el `TextBox` y dando click en el botón de `button1` para llenar el `ListView` (invoco la tabla de la bd a través de un `DataTable`), provoca el siguiente error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter 'buscarValor' not found in the
>   collection.'

Lo cual el reader tiene un valor null.

La verdad que estoy medio perdido y no encuentro la manera de realizarlo.

Aqui el codigo:

La tabla se llama `productos` y tiene 3 columnas: `idproductos` `int`, `nombre_producto` `varchar` y `precio_producto` `int`.

**Stored Procedure**:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BusquedaProductoPorValor`(
buscarValor varchar (50)
)
BEGIN
select *
from productos
where nombre_producto like concat('%',buscarValor,'%');
END
```

**C#**

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                mysqlcon.Open();

                MySqlDataAdapter SqlLista = new MySqlDataAdapter("BusquedaProductoPorValor", mysqlcon);
                SqlLista.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlLista.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("buscarValor", Buscartxt.Text);

                DataTable ListaNueva = new DataTable();

                SqlLista.Fill(ListaNueva);


                dataGridView1.DataSource = ListaNueva;

                MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("BusquedaProductoPorValor", mysqlcon);
                mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                MySqlDataReader Reader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                listView1.Items.Clear();

                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(Reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.GetString(1));
                    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.GetString(2));
                    listView1.Items.Add(lv);

                }
                Reader.Close();






        }
            LimpirarCampos();

        }
```

Comment: En que línea te lanza la excepción? Veo que cuando estás creando el `DataReader` no le estas pasando el parámetro

Comment: Pikoh. Si!! efectivamente. Me faltaba el parametro para la busqueda. Por eso me devolvia el error. Gracias !!

Comment: @Pikoh, por favor publica tu comentario como respuesta para que el OP la acepte. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave gracias, no me di cuenta de que me había contestado el OP. Ya está añadida.

Comment: @AgusVeneziano, el usuario Pikoh ha publicado una respuesta. Si la respuesta a solucionado tu problema. Por favor **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en esta parte de código:

```
MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("BusquedaProductoPorValor", mysqlcon);
mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
MySqlDataReader Reader = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Te falta añadir el parámetro necesario para llamar al procedimiento almacenado:

```
SqlLista.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("buscarValor", Buscartxt.Text);
```